# Streaming Live TV channel from m3u play list

Tags: java, android, streaming, m3u

I am trying  to develop an app for  live channels streaming

But getting trouble when try to play from `m3u` play list .

http://jan.newmarch.name/android/StreamingAudio.html

This  above link describe  Streaming Audio from `m3u` play list . But I want  to

Streaming Video  from m3u play list .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally I got the answer**

You can parse m3u play list Using  by m3u playlist parser Library in java  or U Can create  custom m3u play list parser also.
I would like share the link   one of the m3u playlist parser [Library](https://github.com/saschpe/android-pls-parser)

Comment: Could you explain how to add it to android studio 2.2?

Answer (score 1):

Look into VLC as it has strong streaming capabilities, and support for probably any video/audio format. You will need to integrate [libvlc](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC/) in your app and pass [command-line](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/) options to the libvlc.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question correctly, you want to set up a video streaming server. The mostly common video streaming format for internet is HLS, which uses m3u8 playlists. You can start with ffmpeg using this tutorial (or any of tens of the others):

http://www.bogotobogo.com/VideoStreaming/ffmpeg_http_live_streaming_hls.php

However there are a lot of possible approaches depending on your project scale and requirements.